# Combining line items in cart

Tags: commerce, 9

I am trying to "hide" individual line item values on my shopping cart. Is there a way to combine line items (possibly based on a term applied to each) such that they show as 1 item with the subtotal as the unit price?

As an example:

ungrouped:

- item A - $100
- item B - $50
- item C - $25
- item D - $200
- item E - $50
- item F - $25

grouped

- item A, B, C - $175
- item D, E, F - $275

where line items A, B, C would be tagged when added to cart as Group 1 and C, E, F would be tagged with Group 2.

I am not sure this is doable in the View directly; but possibly in one of the view alter hooks?

### Update:

I am able to use hook_views_pre_render on the commerce_cart_form. From there I can access the line items, evaluate them and remove the line items I want to group in to main item. I just need to sort out what I need to modify to alter the displayed price of the main item. My guess is that I can't easily to do it here without saving the Order Item. I don't really want to modify the Order at all. I just want to display the cart differently.

### Update 2:

Starting to think this is not possible without modifying the stored line item entity. Even preprocessing the Views table where I have access to each cell of the table; it seems as though $variables['rows'] does not use its values from the preprocess function.

Perhaps JS is the only (ugly) was to accomplish this. :(

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more accurate to use attributes on the line items?

Or why do you have this "hidden" line items?

Comment: Line items are products. These are individual products which cost money; but are grouped together as shown in example. The intent is to not show the cost of the individual items, but the cost of the group of items. I do have this working now with JS - but was wondering if a php based way of doing this.